# Python dataframe convert minut data to 30 minute / hour

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I am trying to convert data collected in minuts, into intervals of 30 minutes and 1 hour. The Dataframe is :

```
dateTime            stepsDaily  
2019-11-11 11:58:00 0
2019-11-11 12:00:00 7
2019-11-11 12:01:00 27
2019-11-11 12:08:00 0
2019-11-11 12:13:00 0
... ...
2020-07-26 14:04:00 0
2020-07-26 14:07:00 0
2020-07-26 14:08:00 0
2020-07-26 14:09:00 0
2020-07-26 14:10:00 0
```

I have tried

```
df_steps.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(df_steps.dateTime)
df_steps.set_index("dateTime", drop=True, inplace=True)
df_steps.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_steps30 = df_steps.groupby([df_steps.index.hour]).sum()
```

But this returns

```
dateTime stepsDaily
0   8352
1   9905
2   9154
3   5695
4   5626
5   24485
6   94481
7   155755
8   152925
9   152124
10  183447
11  153881
12  183888
13  235785
14  292723
15  314227
16  276683
17  232000
18  227208
19  209065
20  119630
21  56282
22  18181
```

Which is not what I want. In stead I would like it to return the sum of steps per hour separately, for all days in the dataframe.

Something as:

```
2019-11-11 10:00:00 100
2019-11-11 11:00:00 75
2019-11-11 13:00:00 27
2019-11-11 14:00:00 677
2019-11-11 15:00:00 3
```

Any idea to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.resample()` is the key.

I assume dateTime and stepsDaily are ordinary columns in your data frame.  So you could make dateTime into an index, and then resample in 1-hour steps:

```
df.set_index('dateTime').resample('1h').sum()
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for!